# I take the data from Firestore and show it with a list (card). When I click on the card, I want it to detail the data on a new page

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I get the data from Firestore, but because a text is too long, I cannot show it with a card. I want to be directed to a new page using ontap and see the information on that card in more detail on that page.
how do i do this

```
    dynamic resultant = await DatabaseManager().getUsersList();

    if (resultant == null) {
      print('Unable to retrieve');
    } else {
      setState(() {
        userProfilesList = resultant;
      });
    }
  }

  updateData(String sesAd, String sesKayit, int time, String userID,
      String kelimesayisi) async {
    await DatabaseManager().updateUserList(sesAd, sesKayit, time, userID);
    fetchDatabaseList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Langrec'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: userProfilesList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            onTap: () {
              
              );
            },
            title: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                              Text(
                                userProfilesList[index]()['sesAd'],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontFamily: 'Avenir',
                                ),
                              ),'''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by

**DetailPage**

```
class DetailPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final DocumentSnapshot doc;
  DetailPage({this.doc});
  @override
  _DetailPageState createState() => _DetailPageState();
}

class _DetailPageState extends State<DetailPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Now from your `onTap` you can navigate to the detail page by the following code

```
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DetailPage(doc: userProfilesList,),));
```

To access the document you can use `widget.doc`  which is a document snapshot object.

Ex:

```
Text('${widget.doc["Text"]}'),
```

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for your answer. but I'm getting the error:  'type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot' '

Comment: @wedrash replace ```final DocumentSnapshot doc;``` with ```final String text```
you can use ```widget.text``` to access the data and also change the name in the constructor

Comment: If the answer helped, please upvote it. In this way the community can easily identify the solution.